# Activity indicator swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

I'm trying to set up an activity indicator on my TableView where is my news feed is displayed. So I want that idicator to appear whenever load starts and disappear when it ends.

I know there is a function for webView like this:

```
 func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    activityView.removeFromSuperview()

}
func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
     self.view.addSubview(activityView)
}
```

But it won't work for Table View obviously. Can someone suggest a solution?

I've tried to apply an activity indicator both in the center of my screen and in my Status bar but to no succsess.

I can add full code of my TableView controller if needed.

Thank you!

**EDIT**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Cell height.
    self.tableView.rowHeight = 70
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.delegate = self

  url = NSURL(string: "http---")!
    //url = NSURL(string: "http---")!
   //url = NSURL(string: "http---")!
    loadRss(url);
```

Comment: The solution depends too much on the design. For example, you could show a row with an activity indicator when it's loading, or show the network indicator at the status bar, or show an alert view with the activity indicator, or even use an external library like SVProgressHUD. You have to specify exactly what you want.

Comment: @redent84 if I want to add an activity indicator in my status bar, how do I set up a condition for it?

Comment: http://tuhocswift.com/lap-trinh-swift-can-ban/lap-trinh-swift-activity-indicator-webview.html

Answer (score 0):

To show the small activity indicator in the status bar

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
}

func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
}
```

Comment: How should I set up a condition for this indicator? Should it be based on my NSURL load? I've updated my post.

Comment: Of course you should write first string before you start request and in finish/error block stop the indicator.

Answer (score -3):

show the small activity 
[This is links you can see the answer](http://tuhocswift.com/lap-trinh-swift-can-ban/lap-trinh-swift-activity-indicator-webview.html)

Comment: Can you please explain what is being linked to so that this answer works if the link changes? Also, the linked-to-content is not in the same language as the question or the answer, so we'd appreciate you help translating it, if you can.